# pandoc creates html file that does not format code blocks

Tags: html, r, knitr, pandoc

I am using pandoc to create a html file from an r markdown file, however the code in the html file is not highlighted or formatted, where the html file created from knithtml does show formatting. the pandoc command I am using is:

```
system('pandoc -s -t slidy mdown.md -o mdown.html')
```

Am I perhaps missing a flag option here?

Comment: My guess: you have to manually include some CSS to define the kind of formatting you want. If that's not it, it would help if you could post a minimal example.

Comment: Is this at all useful? http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/misc/pandoc_diffs.html